# Can favicon be same color as tab name?

Tags: favicon

#### The problem

Let's suppose I've got an outlined favicon.

It looks perfect on the selected tab with white background:
[image: Black on white gives enough contrast to be seen]

But if the tab is inactive / user prefers a dark theme icon cannot be visible:
[image: Dark bluish icon is not seen on black]

[Minimal example](https://gm0u6.csb.app/)

**Is it possible to make icon same color with tab text?**

#### What i've tried

Only my idea was to make `svg` favicon with `fill="currentColor"` (rather a silly thing, I know):

```html
<!-- ... -->
<path d="M13 7H11V17H13V7Z" fill="currentColor"></path>
<!-- ... -->
```

But it is not working.

Comment: This might help you [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55170708/detect-if-the-browser-is-using-dark-mode-and-use-a-different-favicon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55170708/detect-if-the-browser-is-using-dark-mode-and-use-a-different-favicon)

Comment: @iamabdm There was the same answer, but it was deleted by author. But, thanks.

Comment: Honestly, I also tried that but it did not work until I turned on dark mode, on the pc, not on the browser. But I would recommend you to not use the '#000' (hex color code), instead you can use '#24292e', '#4078c0',etc, as GitHub does (although they have a black favicon).