# How make a page's icon responsive to the user's color scheme preference?

Tags: html, favicon

Pages offer icons for the browser either via `favicon.ico` or via various `<link>` tags like

```
<link rel='icon' type='image/png' href='icon.png'>
```

The problem is if the icon is the same color as the browser's tabs then you can't see it.

[image: chrome with custom theme]

[image: safari]

[image: firefox]

There are some semi-obvious solutions

(1) as a user, pick theme whose tabs are not pure white or pure black (and pray the sites don't choose the same color)

(2) as a developer, pick an icon color that's not pure white or pure black (and pray it doesn't match the user's theme) or add a frame to the icon.

But, just curious, as a developer, is there a way to tell the browser to use one icon if the tab is dark and a different icon if the tab is light? SVG CSS for example? Different `<link>` tags?

<sub>PS: Yes, I get that the theme above is gaudy. It's "green for google" vs other profiles I use to separate accounts. That way it's easy for me to know which account each browser window is using. [I have 7+ profiles, each with a different and very distinct theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFrwW.jpg)</sub>

Comment: I forgot that theming was even, or ever, a thing in browsers; interesting question.

Comment: Duplicated question [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55170708/detect-if-the-browser-is-using-dark-mode-and-use-a-different-favicon)

Answer (score 2):

You're talking about two possible things:

1. Browser theme
2. OS color scheme

Your screenshot depicts the first. Chrome does not expose a user's chosen theme to its Javascript APIs. Nor does any other browser to my knowledge. That's probably a good thing: it would be *extremely* unique – therefore a way to [fingerprint users](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_fingerprint).

But the second, OS color scheme, is exposed to browsers! This is *usually* only either one of `dark` or `light`. Not every operating system supports color schemes, but the ones that do typically use terms like "Dark Mode" when they talk about it. [Apple has some documentation](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208976) on how to use Dark Mode on macOS, for example.

If an OS supports color schemes, they're exposed to the browser through [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme): `@media ( prefers-color-scheme: dark )`. It's a feature with [>91% global browser support](https://caniuse.com/prefers-color-scheme).

The nice thing about it being in CSS is that you can thus serve an SVG for your favico that *has that media query in it*, and your users will automatically get the right one.

Thomas Steiner popularized this technique in [this 2019 post](https://blog.tomayac.com/2019/09/21/prefers-color-scheme-in-svg-favicons-for-dark-mode-icons/). An example of that:

```xml
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100">
  <style>
    path {
      fill: black;
    }

    @media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
      path {
        fill: white;
      }
    }
  </style>
  <path d="....." />
</svg>
```

Back to your post, though: a user could potentially have a `dark` color scheme, *and* a (say) gaudy green browser theme, so the favico would possibly look bad either way. No avoiding it.

The easiest solution, then?

**Put a background color on your favico**. A solution as old as time!

Comment: did you actually test this and see it works because AFAIK it does not. I tried it before I posted. Note, we're talking about the icon in the tabs not the svg in page.

Comment: "the icon in the tabs" - yep! That's the favico I'm talking about :) Here's a demo page – note that you'll need to refresh after changing your system's Dark Mode setting! https://dark-mode-favicon.glitch.me/

Comment: I guess it fails with themes. It would certainly be possible for the browser to use some heuristic to figure out if the theme is displaying a tab in light or dark colors and choose to use the dark or light version of the icon for that tab.

Comment: That's the first part of my answer :) "Chrome does not expose a user's chosen theme to its Javascript APIs" – it very intentionally is impossible to detect things like tab color from inside the browser! Javascript has no way of knowing things about the surrounding UI.

Comment: So sadly *no*, no heuristic exists that Javascript, CSS, or anything else could use to dynamically change a page off of the application's styles. Chrome Extensions *can* send JS to a page, though, so for completeness's sake you could write a very fancy theme that talks to specific sites to say "hey, switch the favico if this theme in installed." That would only work for sites that you control – you'd need to write the Javascript on both sides.

Comment: The browser has to render the tab. It can certainly look at what colors are being rendered for its heuristic.

Comment: Definitely true. So more precisely: no APIs are exposed that would allow you to build this, as you are a third party developer.

Comment: I didn't ask about APIs 

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be non-standard? as I have not yet found docs but I found a site doing this

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon_white.ico" 
      media="(prefers-color-scheme: dark)"/>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico"
      media="(prefers-color-scheme: light)" />
```

And checking it is picking the correct one in Chrome, at least related to the user's preferred color scheme.

Certainly the `media` attribute applies to `rel="stylesheet"` so maybe it applies to any `<link>`?

Comment: It is standard: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#processing-the-media-attribute:attr-link-media and it applies to all link types, even though it has a real effect only on external resources.